# spark.conf.set with SparkR

Tags: azure, apache-spark, sparkr, databricks, azure-databricks

I have a Databricks cluster running on Azure and want read / write data from Azure Data Lake Storage using `SparkR` / `sparklyr`. Therefore I configured the two [resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/databricks-extract-load-sql-data-warehouse).

Now I have to provide the Spark environment the necessary configurations to authenticate against the Data Lake Storage.

Setting the configs using the `PySpark API` works:

```
    spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.access.token.provider.type", "ClientCredential")
    spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.client.id", "****")
    spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.credential", "****")
    spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/****/oauth2/token")
```

In the end `SparkR` / `sparklyr` should be used. Here I couldn't figure out where to set the `spark.conf.set`. I would have guessed something like:

```
    sparkR.session(
    sparkConfig = list(spark.driver.memory = "2g",
    spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.access.token.provider.type", "ClientCredential"),
    spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.client.id", "****"),
    spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.credential", "****"),
    spark.conf.set("dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/****/oauth2/token")
    ))
```

Would be awesome if one of the experts using the `SparkR` API could help me out here. Thanks!

EDIT:
The answer by user10791349 is correct and it works. Another solution is mounting the external [data source](https://docs.azuredatabricks.net/spark/latest/data-sources/azure/azure-storage.html) which is best practice. This is currently only possible using Scala or Python but the mounted data source is afterwards available using the SparkR API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sparkConfig` [should be](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/R/sparkR.session)

> named list of Spark configuration to set on worker nodes.

So the right format is

```r
sparkR.session(
  ... # All other options
  sparkConfig = list(
    spark.driver.memory = "2g",
    dfs.adls.oauth2.access.token.provider.type = "ClientCredential",
    dfs.adls.oauth2.client.id = "****",
    dfs.adls.oauth2.credential = "****",
    dfs.adls.oauth2.refresh.url ="https://login.microsoftonline.com/****/oauth2/token"
  )
)
```

Remember that the many configuration will be recognized only if there is no active session.